# How do I set a JXTaskPane to be collapsed by default?

Tags: java, jframe, jxtaskpane

Is there a method that sets a JXTaskPane to collapsed by default? Or could you give me some idea how to make a method for what I need?

Answer (score 0):

The method `.setCollapsed(true)` will set the JXTaskPane to collapsed by default.